# CAEmitterLayer - disable animation on touch

Tags: ios, objective-c, calayer

I am trying to add CAEmitterLayer animation to my application. Everything works fine while testing on simulator, however if I run the code on the device, and I start to touch the screen additional cells are emitted completely off the birthrate I set. Is there a way to disable / overview this touch event? I tried by adding:

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
OR
- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

But this does not help. It seems like the touch is taken from different "layer".

Comment: CALayers aren't part of the UIResponder chain and so can't receive touch events themselves. What does your app's view hierarchy look like?

Comment: @ArtGillespie It's simple app with one UIViewController and one view on it. On the viewDidAppear() method CAEmitterLayer is added by calling: [self.view.layer addSublayer:myEmitter]